# High CPU usage, even without a real reason

Tags: cpu, overheating, cpu-load, fancontrol, heat

it's days that the fan and especially the processor of my computer are perennially 100% even if there is no real reason.

This is the situation

Can someone help me?

[image]

This is htop with Chrome close

[image]

Comment: @dsstorefile1 You mean using a command line as "htop"

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Updated the main text

Comment: htop hides kernel threads by default, while top doesn't. You can switch this option off in F2-settings in htop, or use top

Comment: @rtaft Thanks! You Just sayed Kernel but I've not understand if it's a system problem or I Can do something for solve it

Comment: @rtaft Just run htop without hiding the kernel threads

Comment: That time it is Chrome using up the CPU.  Exit out of chrome and redo the screenshot.

Comment: @rtaft updated with the screen without Chrome open

Comment: @rtaft Now I'm using Mozilla and the situation is the same!

Comment: can you post the output of `ubuntu-drivers devices` as well?  And your processor and video card specs.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fjPCjxWw here are!!

Comment: That is not what I asked for...output of `ubuntu-drivers devices` and CPU make/model, GPU make/model

Comment: @rtaft Sorry for misunderstanding in this new pastebin there are all the information! https://pastebin.com/mx1ytnJY Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 11):

I see Chromium browser which is responsible for high CPU as per screenshot provided of `htop` command. 
That simply means there is something wrong with your Chromium browser.
To check for problems, hit Shift+ESC to while using Chromium to bring up the Chromium task manager, and check out which sub-process is using highest CPU, it may be some extension or a Browser Tab.

Also make sure to disable "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" under Chromium Settings>Advanced. This option makes Chromium running even after all Tabs are closed which may cause high resource usage on some systems.

Comment: The red bars are kernel threads, not Chrome

Comment: Thanks! You Just sayed Kernel but I've not understand if it's a system problem or I Can do something for solve it

Comment: @rtaft Updated the main text, can u read above?

Comment: To clarify, this doesn't necessarily mean there is something wrong with Chromium itself, but much more likely to be an issue with a particular web page that is open, or a browser extension.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same thing and tried several things; which I'd found while debugging what the cause was:

1. Disabled the `Accelerated 2D canvas`; can be found here chrome://flags/
2. Disabled most of the GPU processes under that same page.
3. Checked the Task Manager of chrome, which only indicated that the `browser` itself was taking that high CPU(i.e. 151!!)

Tried each one and restarted chrome after each, but in vain! However, `Restore settings to their original defaults` did work. But unfortunately, I don't know what caused the high CPU usage, but yeah that did the trick!

> chrome://settings/ => Advanced Settings => Restore settings...etc

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: restoring the settings did the trick, thanks! it also took a while, so maybe during some upgrade (or switch to snap) something got corrupted

Answer (score 4):

I think your main issue appears to be that you are running in software rendering mode.  This is utilizing your CPU instead of GPU for rendering. Go to Software & Updates on the Additional Drivers tab to make sure you are running the correct video drivers.

I also noticed in your original screenshot of htop that you were 2GB into your swap space.  As you start to run out of swap space, kswapd will chew up a lot of CPU and IO.  The only solutions here is to have less stuff running or to add more memory to the computer.

EDIT:  The op has since changed the screenshot to one where Chrome is using the majority of the CPU.  The original screenshot was not a Chrome issue.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone encountering the high CPU usage issue recently (December 2020), mine was resolved by making sure I had more than 2GB of free disk space on the root partition (Ubuntu 16.04).

This solution was suggested by Martin S. 1301 on this support thread: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/49032533?hl=en&msgid=51383298

Comment: It also solved this issue for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem. In my case it was because of the battery of my laptop. After I removed the faulty battery the problem was solved.

Check this link for more detail: https://askubuntu.com/a/761518/1128551

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the problem might come from a page with a js endless loop. Even after closing that tab, it looks like chromium keeps executing it.

The only thing that stops the high cpu usage is than a chromium reset, which makes go out of all the logged in sites.